# Why do overridden variables get the wrong values in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a class A in Scala, like this one:

```
class A {
  val a = 3
  lazy val b = 2
  println("a = " + a)
  println("b = " + b)
}
```

Next, I extend this class to another class B:

```
class B extends A {
  override val a = 4
  override lazy val b = 3
}
```

Now, when I create an object of `class B`, I get the following output:

```
a = 0  //the default value of int is zero `0` in Scala
b = 3
```

Whereas I was expecting the output to be:

```
a = 3
b = 2
```

My question is how do the `println()` functions in `class A` come to know about the values defined in `class B`, but only of `b` and not of `a`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[docs.scala-lang.org - tutorials - initialization-order](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html) provides a complete explanation.

---

In order to see clearer, let's print the same thing in class `B` as in class `A`:

```
class A {
  val a = 3
  lazy val b = 2
  println("A: a = " + a)
  println("A: b = " + b)
}

class B extends A {
  override val a = 4
  override lazy val b = 3
  println("B: a = " + a)
  println("B: b = " + b)
}
```

In this case, `new B()` produces:

```
A: a = 0
A: b = 3
B: a = 4
B: b = 3
```

---

The initialization order of non-lazy `val` variables is given by:

> In the absence of “early definitions” (see below), initialization of
>   strict vals is done in the following order.
>
> 1. Superclasses are fully initialized before subclasses.
> 2. Otherwise, in declaration order.

Thus `A` is fully initialized before `B`.

But `val` can't be initialized more than once. So internally Scala gives it a default value (`0` for an `Int`, `null` for a `String`, ..) when dealing first with the superclass `A`.

Thus it prints `0` at first (when initializing `A`) and then `4` (when initializing `B`).

---

Using lazy vals is the solution proposed by the [scaladoc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html) to bypass this limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This answer explains a lot about inheritance in Scala.

Comment: How does the first b = 3 make sense? At A's println time, which runs before B's overrides, it accesses b, which is currently set to 2.

Comment: @allidoiswin It runs before B *initializes*, but *after B overrides*. All the code is there, it's just not invoked for `a` during initialization of `A`, because the final variable `a` can be assigned to exactly once. The `lazy val` is more like cached `def`.

Comment: I'm not understanding why println for `a` doesn't also follow "runs after override". Could you elaborate with a step-by-step what is happening? i.e. like so-and-so is initialized, so-and-so has its value set, etc.? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Why `lazy val` works as expected? Because `val` is marked by `lazy` will be initialized on its first access.

Why non-lazy does not work as expected? Because of initialization order.

non-lazy vals are initialized [in the following order](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html):

> 1. Superclasses are fully initialized before subclasses.
> 2. Otherwise, in declaration order.

In your example you're trying to access an `override val`, but an `override val` will appear to be `null` during the construction of superclasses.

Code with more logs to see an initialization order:

```
class A {
  println("First line of A")
  val strictVal: String = {
    println("A.strictVal called")
    "strictVal of A"
  }
  lazy val lazyVal: String = {
    println("A.lazyVal called")
    "lazyVal of A"
  }

  println(s"lazyVal = $lazyVal")
  println(s"strictVal = $strictVal")

  println("Last line of A")
}

class B extends A {
  println("First line of B")
  override val strictVal: String = {
    println("B.strictVal called")
    "strictVal of B"
  }

  override lazy val lazyVal: String = {
    println("B.lazyVal called")
    "lazyVal of B"
  }
  println("Last line of B")
}
```

Output for `new B()`:

```
First line of A
A.strictVal called
B.lazyVal called
lazyVal = lazyVal of B
strictVal = null
Last line of A
First line of B
B.strictVal called
Last line of B
```

Comment: The behavior described in the question was already confusing enough, why did you swapped all the names of the variables, making `a` lazy... Moreover, the `s` in  `s"..."`-string interpolations do not seem to do anything?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin,  thanks, fixed those and changed the example. Hope it's better now