# scala: construction order and early definitions (inheritance)

Tags: scala

I am reading "Scala for the Impatient" and in 8.10 there is an example:

```
class Animal {
  val range: Int = 10
  val env: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](range)

}

class Ant extends Animal {
  override val range: Int = 2
}
```

The author explains why the env ends up being an empty Array[Int]:

> [..]
>   3. The Animal constructor, in order to initialize the env array, calls the range() getter.
>
> 4. That method is overridden to yield the (as yet uninitialized) range field of the Ant class.
> 5. The range method returns 0. (That is the initial value of all integer fields when an object is allocated.)
> 6. env is set to an array of length 0.
> 7. The Ant constructor continues, setting its range field to 2.[..]

I don't understand the 4th and therefore the next steps are also not clear. range() method is overridden with 2, so why doesn't it set the range already in the 4th step?

Doe is work this way? When the val is overridden, then it gets uninitialised and also all val's that include this overridden gals get modified as well. Is it correct? If yes, why there is a different behaviour with def as outlined [here](https://github.com/BasileDuPlessis/scala-for-the-impatient/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/basile/scala/ch08/Ex09.scala). Why is def defined before the constructor call and val after?

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595018/why-do-overridden-variables-get-the-wrong-values-in-scala . This was trending only few hours ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your comment, I decided to actually look at what exactly is written in the book. After reading the explanation, I decided that I cannot express it any clearer. So instead, I propose to take a look at the completely desugared code, for which there was no place in the short book.

Save this as a Scala script:

```
class Animal {
  val range: Int = 10
  val env: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](range)
}

class Ant extends Animal {
  override val range: Int = 2
}

val ant = new Ant
println(ant.range)
println(ant.env.size)
```

and then run it using the `-print`-option:

```
> scala -nc -print yourScript.scala
```

you should see something like this:

```
class anon$1$Animal extends Object {
  private[this] val range: Int = _;
  <stable> <accessor> def range(): Int = anon$1$Animal.this.range;
  private[this] val env: Array[Int] = _;
  <stable> <accessor> def env(): Array[Int] = anon$1$Animal.this.env;
  <synthetic> <paramaccessor> <artifact> protected val $outer: <$anon: Object> = _;
  <synthetic> <stable> <artifact> def $outer(): <$anon: Object> = anon$1$Animal.this.$outer;
  def <init>($outer: <$anon: Object>): <$anon: Object> = {
    if ($outer.eq(null))
      throw null
    else
      anon$1$Animal.this.$outer = $outer;
    anon$1$Animal.super.<init>();
    anon$1$Animal.this.range = 10;
    anon$1$Animal.this.env = new Array[Int](anon$1$Animal.this.range());
    ()
  }
};
class anon$1$Ant extends <$anon: Object> {
  private[this] val range: Int = _;
  override <stable> <accessor> def range(): Int = anon$1$Ant.this.range;
  <synthetic> <stable> <artifact> def $outer(): <$anon: Object> = anon$1$Ant.this.$outer;
  def <init>($outer: <$anon: Object>): <$anon: anon$1$Animal> = {
    anon$1$Ant.super.<init>($outer);
    anon$1$Ant.this.range = 2;
    ()
  }
}
```

This is the desugared code as it is seen by the compiler in later stages of compilation. It's a bit hard to read, but what it is important are these declarations:

```
  // in Animal:
  private[this] val range: Int = _;
  <stable> <accessor> def range(): Int = anon$1$Animal.this.range;

  // in Ant:
  private[this] val range: Int = _;
  override <stable> <accessor> def range(): Int = 
    anon$1$Ant.this.range;
```

and also the statement in the initializer of `Animal`:

```
  anon$1$Animal.this.env = new Array[Int](anon$1$Animal.this.range())
```

What you can see here is that there are actually two different variables `range`: one is `Animal.this.range` and the other is `Ant.this.range`. Moreover, there are completely separate `def`s which are *also* called `range` in the desugared code: these are the getters which are generated automatically for `val`s.

The first variable is indeed initialized in `Animal` and set to `10`:

```
    anon$1$Animal.this.range = 10;
```

However, this does not matter, because the `env` is initialized using the getter `range()`, which is overridden to return `Ant.this.range`. The variable `Ant.this.range` is assigned the value `2` once, but *after* the initializer of `Animal` has completed. During the initialization of `Animal`, the variable `Ant.this.range` holds the default value `0`, hence the counter-intuitive result.

If you simplify the desugared code a little bit, you obtain a compilable and readable example that behaves in the same way:

```
class Animal {
  private[this] var _Animal_range: Int = 0
  def range: Int = _Animal_range

  _Animal_range = 10
  val env: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](range)
}

class Ant extends Animal {
  private[this] var _Ant_range: Int = 0
  override def range: Int = _Ant_range

  _Ant_range = 2
}

val ant = new Ant
println(ant.range)
println(ant.env.size)
```

Here, the same happens:

1. `_Animal_range` is allocated with default value 0
2. `_Ant_range` is allocated with default value 0
3. `Animal` base class begins initialization
4. `_Animal_range` is initialized with value 10
5. To initialize `env`, the getter `range` is invoked. It is overridden in the `Ant`-class, and returns `_Ant_range`, which is still 0
6. `env` is set to an empty array
7. `Animal` base class finishes initialization
8. `Ant` begins initialization
9. Only now does it set `_Ant_range` to `2`.

This is why both code snippets print `2` and `0`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It he book the say:  1.  The Ant constructor calls the Animal constructor before doing its own construction. 2. The Animal constructor sets its range field to 10. 3. The Animal constructor, in order to initialize the env array, calls the range() getter.

Comment: @Tonja I've added the desugared code to show what's going on under the hood, and then translated it into a shorter piece of code with variables `_Animal_range` and `_Ant_range` that are clearly separated from the getter `range`. The getter is not the same thing as the variables, it's a separate synthetic method that is generated together with the variable from a single `val` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

`def`s are called when asked for, but `val`s are kept in memory, so in this case the `val` version is still set to zero because it hasn’t been initialised, where the `def` version is called and therefore can never give a misleading value.

It’s only because the `val` here is overloaded that it isn’t initialised in time, because classes must be initialised starting at the top of the inheritance hierarchy and building down. If `env` were a `def` you’d be fine also, because it wouldn’t be created until called, by which time the `val`s would all be initialised. Of course this way you’d get different lists every time you called `env` so you might prefer to use `lazy val`, which is initialised the first time it’s called, but then remains the same and is kept in memory.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I was thinking of var. That’ll teach me to answer questions in languages I haven’t seen in a while. I believe the rest of my answer stands though. Have you tried the latter? I can’t think why that would be.

Comment: Why wasn't it initialised? First it gets initialised by the Animal class, then it is overridden by the Ant and therefore should instantly be initialised. And this is not the case, why does it get unintilised in-between?

Comment: I think the way polymorphic inheritance like this works means that the memory for everything is allocated up front (and set to zero because this is the jvm), and then when the superclass value is initialised it is set to point to the allocated memory in the subclass for its val, which is zero until the subclass is initialised. I’m a little fuzzy on some of the detail, in particular where those pointers are kept, but it must be something like that.

Comment: Do you know if this is the case for Python as well?

Comment: I don’t know, but I think python takes a different approach to construction so it might be more forgiving.

Comment: It’s probably more transparent in python because the properties don’t exist at all until created by an init method or somewhere else. As you have to chain those yourself you should always be able to see what exists when.

Comment: Just found this in the same book:  In C++, an object’s virtual function table pointer is set to the table of the superclass when the superclass constructor executes. Afterwards, the pointer is set to the subclass table. Therefore, in C++, it is not possible to modify constructor behavior through overriding. The Java designers felt that this subtlety was unnecessary, and the Java virtual machine does not adjust the virtual function table during construction.

Comment: @Tonja Neat. +1